# perl check a line contains at list one word of an array

Tags: perl

I have a file containing a few words, let's take for example this file :

```
balloon
space
monkey
fruit
```

I want to check if a string contains at least one of these words. I stored all the words in an array, like this (the file is specified in parameters) :

```
open my $exampleFile, '<', $ARGV[0];
chomp(my @exampleWords= <$exampleFile>);
close $exampleFile;
```

Then I use `grep` to check if one of these words is in the string:

```
if ( grep( $string, @exampleWords ) ) 
{
    #do something
}
```

If I take for example the string `this_is_a_balloon_example`, the word `balloon` has been found so I should enter the loop. At the moment, the loop seems to be entered for any string given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `grep` is checking for true value, and `$string` is almost always 'truthy'.
What you need is regex which tests if `$string` matches againts `$_`,

```
if ( grep($string =~ /$_/, @exampleWords ) ) 
{
    #do something
}
```

Comment: It seems to work, but is there a way to ignore case-sensitive ?

Comment: Yes, use `i` switch, `.. =~ /$_/i`.

Answer (score 6):

`grep` iterates a list. It can be fairly inefficient as a result.

I would suggest that what you want to do is compile a regex.

```
my $regex = join "|", @examplewords; 
$regex    = qr/\b($regex)\b/; 

if ( $string =~ m/$regex/ ) { 
    print "There was a match on $1\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl's [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) does not work like the [command line utility `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html). You're simply checking if `$string` is true, which is always the case. If you want to check if any of the words in `@exampleWords` is contained in `$string`, you need to tell Perl that.

```
if ( grep { $string =~ m/$_/} @exampleWords ) {
    ...
}
```

This uses a pattern match.

Alternatively, you could also use [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html), which returns the position of the first occurrence of the substring, in this case `$_`, or `-1`.

```
if ( grep { index( $string, $_ ) != -1 } @exampleWords ) { 
    ... 
}
```

The pattern match is easier to read though, and in terms of performance it really doesn't make a difference.