# Perl check if a line starting with a word from an array and return the matched value to variable

Tags: arrays, perl, match

I checked following topic [Perl check a line contains at list one word of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658293/perl-check-a-line-contains-at-list-one-word-of-an-array), but I still confuse how to make it more efficient for my case.

I use example from topic above.

I have an array, called @exampleWords:

```
my @exampleWords = ("balloon", "space", "monkey", "fruit" );
```

and I have a line contains of a sentence for example:

```
my $line = "monkey space always unlimited";
```

How do I can check if $line starting with a match word in array, and return the matched word into a variable?

in example above, the matched word is "monkey".

current solution in my mind is: loop each word in array and check if the $line starting with a $word.

```
my $matchWord = "";
foreach my $word(@exampleWords) {
  if ($line =~ /^$word/) {
    $matchWord = $word;
    last;
  }
}
```

I am still looking more efficient solution..

thank you...

Comment: *"I still confuse how to make it more efficient for my case"* Why do you want to make it more efficient? Have you tested what you have and found that it is too slow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In principle, you have to iterate over possible words to match.  However, you can also construct an alternation regex pattern with them so that the regex engine starts once, unlike with the loop where it is started for *every* iteration. Also, now the iteration goes by highly optimized C code.

How do these compare? Let's benchmark them, using the core module [Benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html).

**For a tiny array, matching around its middle** (your example)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Benchmark qw( cmpthese );

my @ary = ("balloon", "space", "monkey", "fruit");
my $line = "monkey space always unlimited";

sub regex {
    my ($line, @ary) = @_;
    my $match; 
    my $re = join '|', map { quotemeta } @ary;
    if ($line =~ /^($re)/) {
        $match = $1;
    }   
    return $match;
}   

sub loop {
    my ($line, @ary) = @_;
    my $match; 
    foreach my $word (@ary) {
        if ($line =~ /^$word/) {  # see note at end
            $match = $word;
            last;
        }   
    }   
    return $match;
}   

cmpthese(-10, {
    regex => sub { regex ($line, @ary) },
    loop  => sub { loop  ($line, @ary) },
});
```

This produces, on both a very good machine with v5.16 and on an older one with  v5.10

```
          Rate  loop regex
loop  222791/s    --  -70%
regex 742962/s  233%    --
```

Thus regex is way more efficient.

**For a 40 times larger array, matching around the middle**

I build this array by `@ary = qw(...) x 20`, then add a word (`'AHA'`), then repeat 20 more times. I prepend that very word to the string, so that's what gets matched. I make the string much larger, too, even though this shouldn't matter for matching.

In this case the regex is even more convincing

```
         Rate  loop regex
loop   9300/s    --  -82%
regex 50873/s  447%    --
```

and yet more so with v5.10 on the older machine, with `574%`.

On v5.27.2 the regex is faster by `1188%`, so by a clean order of magnitude. But it is the rate of the loop that drops to only `6723/s`, against the above `9330/s`. So this only shows that the regex "startup" is more expensive in newer Perls, thus the loop falls further behind.

**For the same large array, with the match word near its beginning**

I move the match-word `AHA` in the array right past the original 4-word list

```
         Rate  loop regex
loop  36710/s    --   -3%
regex 37666/s    3%    --
```

So the match needs to happen very, very early so that the loop catches up with the regex.  While this can happen often in specific use cases it cannot be expected in general, of course.

Note that the regex had far less work to do as well. Thus it's clear that the loop's problem is that it starts the regex engine anew for every iteration.  Here it only had to do it a few times and the regex's advantage all but evaporated, even though it also matched much sooner.

---

As for programmer's efficiency, take your pick. There are yet other ways using higher level libraries so that you don't have to write the loop. For instance, using core [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html)

```
use List::Util qw(first);

my $match = first { $line =~ /^$_/ } @ary;
```

This benchmarks between the same and around 10% *slower* than your loop when added.

---

A note on regex used in the question.

If the first word in `$line` is `puppy` the regex `/^$word/` will match it with `pup`. This may or may not be intended (but think of `flu` for `fluent` instead), but if it isn't it can be fixed by adding the *word boundary* anchor `\b`,

```
$line =~ /^$word\b/
```

The same can be used with the alternation pattern, which was written so to mimic the code in the question. So add the word boundary anchor, for `/^($re)\b/`.

Another way is to sort the list by the length of words, `sort { length $b <=> length $a } @ary`, per [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin)'s comment. This may affect the problem in a more complex way, please consider.

Comment: hi Thanks for your response. actually, the system where I run this script has very limited resources and perl modules. will consider your solutions. btw, I would like also consider what if item in the @ary in your sample is consists of "not single word", but "multi words" in an item. will the benchmark results changes?

Comment: @guete  There is no need for resources or Perl modules.  I am simply showing you a comparison of your (good) approach and of that with a regex.  As you can see, the regex is much faster in general.  Time these two on your machines/resources, it should come out very similar.  The _only_ module used is in the core, `Benchmark`.  I am adding the link to the answer...

Comment: example: my @ary = ("balloon red", "space monkey", "monkey", "fruit jelly" );

Comment: @guete  Alright, I'll revert the `qw(...)` ... but then, does your string still start with `monkey`? If so, it's the same: the regex pattern is now `/^(ballon red|space monkey|monkey...)/`, which again matches on `monkey`.

Comment: @guete  Restored your list of quoted words

Comment: yes @zdim, my regex pattern could be more complex than simple word, it could consists of multiple words and non-alphabet characters. I tried your sample to suits my case, it works perfectly. and Benchmark also shows not so much different than single word. Thank you very much! appreciated! :)

Comment: @guete  Glad that it helped :)  The alternation pattern does not in fact do much more than the regex you use in the loop (while it can if needed).  I'll add anotherexample when I get to it (tomorrow?), will let you know.

Comment: `my $re = join '|', @ary` should probably be `my $re = join '|', map { quotemeta } sort { length $b <=> length $a } @ary` to allow for some of the words containing regex metacharacters or being substrings of others.

Comment: @Borodin  Thank you, I am adding `quotemeta` (didn't want to descend into that but this isn't quite right the way it is). As for telling a `bookcase` from a `book` ... I had decided to focus on the stated question and use their code, so to not comment on their `/^$word/` without `\b` ... but looking back I think I should. Thank you, will add a note at the end.